# Why is my program only printing the last section of an array?

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans, filereader

So my professor let us copy this certain code but we have to fill in the blanks on some parts to make the program work. I'm supposed to create a two-dimensional array using the "Classics.txt" file and print the output. My problem is when I run the program, it only shows the last section of the array.

PS. I put a comment on the parts where I input the code myself. My professor instructed us not to edit the code that we copied from him.

Thanks in advance.

```js
import java.io.*;
public class CompactDisc {

    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
        FileReader file = new FileReader("Classics.txt");
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(file);
        String title = null;
        String artist = null;
                // CODE I INPUT MYSELF
        int column = 0;
        String cd[][] = new String[6][6];
                // END
        for (int i = 0; i < cd.length; i++) {
                // CODE I INPUT MYSELF
            title = input.readLine();
            artist = input.readLine();
            cd[i][column] = title;
            column++;
            cd[i][column] = artist;
            column = 0;
                // END
        }
        System.out.println("Contents of Classics:");
        for (int i = 0; i < cd.length; i++) {
                // CODE I INPUT MYSELF
            Song track = new Song(title, artist);
            System.out.print(track);
                // END
        }
    }
}

class Song extends CompactDisc{
    private String title; // The song's title
    private String artist; // The song's artist
    /**
    Constructor
    @param title A reference to a String object
    containing the song's title.
    @param artist A reference to a String object
    containing the song's artist.
    */
    public Song(String title, String artist) {
        this.title = title;
        this.artist = artist;
    }
    /**
    The toString method
    @return A String object containing the name
    of the song and the artist.
    */
    public String toString() {
    return title + " by " + artist + "\n";
    }
}
```

This is what's in the "Classics.txt" file:

```js
Ode to Joy
Bach
The Sleeping Beauty
Tchaikovsky
Lullaby
Brahms
Canon
Bach
Symphony No. 5
Beethoven
The Blue Danube Waltz
Strauss
```

And this is the output it's giving:

```js
Contents of Classics:
The Blue Danube Waltz by Strauss
The Blue Danube Waltz by Strauss
The Blue Danube Waltz by Strauss
The Blue Danube Waltz by Strauss
The Blue Danube Waltz by Strauss
The Blue Danube Waltz by Strauss
```

Comment: Step through your code with the debugger. Hint: you put data into the array. Do you use it later?

Comment: Tangential: a song isn’t a kind of CD—a CD **has** songs, which is different.

Comment: @DaveNewton HAHA I know! It's just the first variable name that came to my mind at that moment.

Comment: @tgdavies Thank you so much! I feel so dumb not even noticing the most obvious answer to my problem. My program runs perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

Using a multidimensional `String[]` to store `Song`(s) seems wrong to me, I would create a `Song[]` instead. You can read all of the lines of your file at once with [`Files.readAllLines(Path, Charset)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)) you then know that every two lines represents one `Song`, so loop and fill a `Song[]` and then print the contents. Something like,

```
List<String> al = Files.readAllLines(Path.of("Classics.txt"),
        Charset.forName("UTF8"));
Song[] cd = new Song[al.size() / 2];
int p = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i += 2) {
    cd[p] = new Song(al.get(i), al.get(i + 1));
    p++;
}
System.out.println("Contents of Classics:");
for (Song track : cd) {
    System.out.print(track);
}
```

Of course, you could potentially eliminate the array and second loop

```
List<String> al = Files.readAllLines(Path.of("Classics.txt"),
        Charset.forName("UTF8"));
System.out.println("Contents of Classics:");
for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i += 2) {
    System.out.println(new Song(al.get(i), al.get(i + 1)));
}
```

Comment: Why not `StandardCharsets.UTF_8`?

Comment: I cannot really do this one since my professor doesn't let us edit some parts of the code. It's sort of like fill in the blanks kind of activity.

Comment: @PatPatis You should probably look up your school's academic code of conduct regarding assistance with assignments. `String cd[][] = new String[6][6];` is wrong. The second dimension should be `2`; and the first should be half of the number of lines in `Classics.txt`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I'm pretty sure I can at least ask for some guidance here regarding my assignments. It's not like I'm asking people to do my program for me. I'm simply just seeking for help. Anyway, thank you for pointing out the size of my two-dimensional array, I had it fixed.